# Script parses very few titles out of many from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to get all the titles from a webpage using python in combination with selenium as the content are heavily dynamic. However, when I run my script, it just fetches first few of them. The selectors I've defined within my script seems to be flawless.

***[Webpage address](https://www.groupon.com/browse/new-orleans?badge=top-seller&query=med+spa)***

How can I get all the titles from that page?

I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "find_the_site_link_above"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "figure[data-pingdom-info='purchasable-deal']"))):   
    name = items.find_element_by_css_selector(".cui-udc-title").text
    print(name)
driver.quit()
```

The above script produces first few links whereas they are many more in number.

```
Chronos Med Spa
Planet Beach Spray & Spa
Spa at Fountain Park Beauty Bar
Reset Body & Skin
7th Sense Wellness and Massage
Body Art Day Spa & Salon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to wait until the page is completely loaded. There are different ways to do it with different measure of success. The easiest way is to look for the element which loads at the end of the page. In this case, i am adding a wait for trending deals section,

```
 wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='compound-title']")))

    for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "figure[data-pingdom-info='purchasable-deal']"))):   
        name = items.find_element_by_css_selector(".cui-udc-title").text
        print(name)
```

Comment: That still gives me the exact same results which I was having already.

Comment: After this step, i got length as 48 and able to print all of those text. You can try adding some additional wait after closing the popup window.

Comment: If I put `time.sleep(3)` right before `for items in wait.until()` without closing that popup modal I get all the results but I don't wish to use any hardcoded delay. The bottom line is I'm still getting 6 results following exactly what you have suggested.